seaborn histplot column is placed at a wrong location
I've this simple csv file



A
B
C




A1
4
11


A1
7
13


A1
4
9


A1
7
13


A2
3
10


A2
3
10


A2
6
12


A2
3
10



The pandas dataframe looks correct
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)

    A  B   C
0  A1  4  11
1  A1  7  13
2  A1  4   9
3  A1  7  13
4  A2  3  10
5  A2  4  10
6  A2  6  12
7  A2  3  10

I'm trying to plot a joint distributions of B and C using seaborn JointGrid as follows
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.JointGrid(
    data=df,
    x='C',
    y='B',
    hue='A',
    xlim=(df['C'].min() - 1, df['C'].max() + 1),
    ylim=(df['B'].min() - 1, df['B'].max() + 1),
    marginal_ticks=True
)
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, s=60, alpha=.5)
g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, kde=True, line_kws={ 'linewidth': 1 })

But plot is coming up wrong:

Looking at the data it's obvious that the last blue bars should be shifted by 1 unit.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Did you try to tell seaborn about the discreteness of the data: g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, discrete=True, ...)?

I see, that was the issue. Thank you.

@dibyendu Please post that as an answer if it solved your problem.
